# SQL SELECT: match a PK to a tuple and from value of that tuple select others that have same value to that tuple?

Tags: sql, select

I'm stuck with a homework..

How can I from this table check what cID, sID = '03' are taking? And with that, checking other sID that got the same cID as sID = '03' and select it out?

```
sID    cID      year     grades
--------------------------------
01    L21D   1997   4
01    L24D   1998   2
01    L32D   1998   3
02    L21D   1998   3
02    L32D   1998   4
03    L32D   1998
```

This is what I want to select:

```
sID   cID 
-------------
01   L32D 
02   L32D 
03   L32D
```

I've tried different combinations, but none have given what I wanted. Maybe I'm too tired for the moment.

For example I tried this:

`SELECT sID 
FROM studentcourse 
WHERE sID = 
( 
SELECT cID 
FROM studentcourse 
WHERE sID = '03'
)`

BR, Jay

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give an example of the results you want as well, with comments.

Comment: How far have you gotten? People are more likely to help if you show you've put some effort in yourself.

Comment: Jay, you should edit your question to add that stuff.

Comment: ohh man it's messed up now. How do I add code to the comments??

Comment: Jay, add it to the question instead - comments aren't meant for that sort of thing.

Comment: @Jay - it's best just to edit the original post if you are clarifying it.

Comment: I moved your comments as an edit to the original question. You can't format in comments.

Comment: Is it considered a match if the other student has any courses in common? Do they have to have exactly the same courses? What if one student is taking a subset of courses that another student has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes that sID = '03' is taking:

```
Select cID from StudentsInClasses where sID = '03'
```

Students who at some time took the same class as sID = '03' (including sID = '03'):

```
Select 
    sID
From
    StudentsInClasses
Where
    cID in (Select cID from StudentsInClasses where sID = '03')
```

Comment: Thank you! 

At least I was close to making it right ^^'

Thank you guys. See you around :) 

I like this forum. Great name :)

Comment: @jdnhldn You can always show a little love and click the check mark next to the answer that you like best, too.

Comment: just firgured out what love is :)

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the cID(s) where sID is '03':

```
select cID from table where sID = '03'
```

One way to get other sID(s) with the same cID, is to put the above query into a subquery:

```
select * from table
where cID in (
    select cID from table where sID = '03'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT cId, SId
 from table
 WHERE (cId, SID) IN (Select CId, SId from Table
                 WHERE sId = '03')
```

Result will be:

01  L32D
02  L32D
03  L32D

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT t.cid, 
            t.sid
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN TABLE x ON x.cid = t.cid
                    AND x.sid = '03'
```

It's more readable as IN:

```
SELECT t.cid,
            t.sid
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.cid IN (SELECT x.cid
                          FROM TABLE x
                         WHERE x.sid = '03')
```

Using EXISTS:

```
SELECT t.cid,
            t.sid
    FROM TABLE t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                        FROM TABLE x
                      WHERE x.cid = t.cid
                          AND x.sid = '03')
```